# Signing information while generating APKs from app bundle

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

Android documentation states that, we should pass signing information to the "build-apks" command in order to deploy apks to the device. I am not passing any signing information to "build-apks" command, but still I am able to deploy apks to my device. From the logs, I have observed that apks are auto signed with android debug keystore. Is the android documentation regarding "building apks from bundle" is wrong or my understanding is wrong ?

doc link and snippet:
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool

" bundletool build-apks --bundle=/MyApp/my_app.aab --output=/MyApp/my_app.apks

Note that the command above creates an APK set of unsigned APKs. If you want to deploy the APKs to a device, you need to also include your app’s signing information, as shown in the command below. "

Note : I am using bundletool 0.9.0 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a recent change that happened in bundletool 0.8.0. See the [release notes](https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases/tag/0.8.0).

It seems that the documentation has not been updated yet. Thanks for pointing it out, I'll have it updated.

Answer (score 1):

For further info,

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128954041

"The documentation should be updated: In bundletool 0.8.0 and above, the build-apks will attempt to sign it with your debug key if available automatically:

For more information regarding the release see: https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases/tag/0.8.0."